# soapui vs eclipse webservice explorer

Tags: web-services, eclipse

I want to test fairly simple wsdls (with basic ws-security support) from inside eclipse- the main aim is to invoke webservices and capture the output for use in other supporting tooling. Performance/load testing is not a use case. I want to know how the Eclipse WTP webservice explorer compares with soapui. Questions: will the wtp tool serve my purpose? is soapui overkill?